# How to change the modules order of appearance?

Tags: module-display

My main module seems to load last among other less important modules. 
How can I make change the order of appearance of the modules on my site?

Comment: Maybe because there's more data/assets to be loaded. Could you please provide a link to your site and tell us which module you're referring to?

Comment: Do you mean that it is displayed below other modules in the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I understand from your question, is that a specific module, which you would like to display it at higher position on the page, before other modules, it is displayed lower.

Well, for this there are 2 main things to check.

## 1. Module's actual Position

The module position that the module is assigned to.
You must put it on a position that is higher in your template - actually at the position where you want it appear.

## 2. Module's order in the given position

Now, if you have more than 1 modules assigned to the same position, make sure you have set your desired order of appearance in Module Manager.

For this:

1. Filter the modules list by position - selecting the position in question-
2. Then order the modules by order.
3. Drag up/down modules to set their order. Put your main order on Top.

[image: Module Manager - Setting Module's order for specific position]